# Have bottom var accessible on top

Tags: javascript, function, alpine.js

Make JS function at bottom set var at top.

My js function `post_count_function` only works at the bottom of my JS. Not sure why.

but I need to pass the var to the top to use in a different function, is there a simple solution?

I need `post_count` at the top, but if I place the function at the top of the page I get not defined

```
var post_count = 0;


Alpine.data("filterPosts", (adminURL) => ({
  posts: "",
  limit: 6,
  category: 0,
  post_type_js: post_id,
  showDefault: true,
  showFiltered: false,
  offset: 0,
  total: 0,


  filterPosts(id) {
    this.showDefault = false;
    this.showFiltered = true;
    this.category = id;
    this.offset = 0; // <-- reset offset to zero
    this.fetchPosts();
    this.total = post_count;
  },

  loadMore() {
    this.loadingMore = true;
    this.offset += 6;
    this.showFiltered = true;
    this.fetchPosts(true);
  },

  fetchPosts(append = false) {
    var formData = new FormData();
    formData.append("action", "filterPosts");
    formData.append("limit", this.limit);
    formData.append("post_type_js", this.post_type_js);
    formData.append("offset", this.offset);

    if (this.category) {
      formData.append("category", this.category);
      formData.append("total", this.total);
    }

    fetch(adminURL, {
        method: "POST",
        body: formData,
      })
      .then((res) => res.json())
      .then((res) => {
        if (append) {
          // Appends posts to the end of existing posts data
          this.posts = this.posts.concat(res.posts);
        } else {
          // Resets the posts data with new data
          this.posts = res.posts;
        }

        this.loading = false;
      });
  },

  getTotal() {
    var formData = new FormData();
    formData.append("action", "filterPosts");
    fetch(adminURL, {
        method: "POST",
        body: formData,
      })
      .then((res) => res.json())
      .then((res) => {
        this.total = res.total;
      });
  },

  init() {
    this.getTotal();
  }

}));
})

function post_count_function(obj) {
  var post_count = obj.getAttribute('data-value')
  console.log("post amount", post_count);
}
```

Comment: Your variable at the top is in the global scope, but the one you set in your function with `var post_count` is scoped to that function and will not affect the top one. These are two separate variables. Have you tried removing the `var` from `post_count_function()`?

Comment: good idea, ill try now

Comment: @mykaf unfortunately now

Comment: Unfortunately now what?

Comment: sorry, unfortunately it did not work

Comment: What happened this time? Please edit your question with updated code.

Comment: will do, 10 mins